# Tracking the facebook like button

Tags: javascript, facebook-like

I have a Facebook like button on my page, and I'd like to track when it is clicked (and by which user, etc).  I have the javascript below running (gives alert "running"), but it doesn't give the alert "You liked the URL...", which is where I will put all of my logic:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {    
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    alert("running")
    FB.Event.subscribe('edge.create',
      function(response) {
        alert('You liked the URL: ' + response);
      }
    );
  };
});
```

Does anyone know why this is not firing when the like button is clicked?

**EDIT**
I'm referencing this page when trying to set it up: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/

**EDIT 2**
I'm adding the like button via iframe (the button itself works properly):

```
<span id="facebook-share-btn">
  <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<%= item.short_path %>&amp;send=false&amp;layout=button_count&amp;width=450&amp;show_faces=false&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;action=like&amp;height=35" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:48px; height:22px;" allowTransparency="true">
  </iframe>
</span>
```

Comment: How are you adding the like button to your site?  Html5, XFBML, or iframe?

Comment: @Fisch I'm adding it via iframe -- I'll edit the question to show the code.  Will the js not pick up the iframe?

Comment: Correct.  The I frame version does not work with facebooks event subscription model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the callbacks do not work (apparently) with the iframe method.  I've switched to the HTML5 method and it works fine.

#### Setup:

```
<div id='fb-root'></div>
<script>
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  FB.init({appId: "myId", status: true, cookie: true});

</script>
```

#### Like button:

```
<div class="fb-like" 
     data-href="myurl.com" 
     data-send="false" 
     data-layout="button_count" 
     data-width="450" 
     data-show-faces="false">
</div>
```

Comment: this is what i was getting at when i asked my question of you.  the the iframe version does not work with subscribing to events.